# What is the correct argument should i pass to the word function PrintOut() to print only the page number 2

Tags: python-3.x, ms-office, win32com

i have a word document,it has 37 pages and i just want to print only the page number 2,i found the function PrintOut(),but the argument is not work,it always print all the pages.

i found this webpage
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.Document.PrintOut
it tells me every argument，but it is not work.

```
import win32com.client as win32

xWord =win32.DispatchEx('Word.Application')

Dc=xWord.Documents.Open(r'C:\Users\X\Desktop\work.docx')

Dc.PrintOut(Background=False, Append=False, Range=4, OutputFileName="", From=0, To=0, Item=0, Copies=1, Pages="2", PageType=0, PrintToFile=False, Collate=True, ManualDuplexPrint=False, PrintZoomColumn=1, PrintZoomRow=1, PrintZoomPaperWidth=0, PrintZoomPaperHeight=0)
```

I've tried the following

- 1、Dc.PrintOut(Range=4,Item=0, Copies=1, Pages="2", PageType=0)
- 2、Dc.PrintOut(Range=4,Item=0,Pages="2", PageType=0)

but the argument is not work,it always print all the pages.

Answer (score 0):

To print the current page you can use the following parameters as shown in the sample code (C#):

```
object copies = "1"; 
object pages = "1"; 
object range = Word.WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintCurrentPage; 
object items = Word.WdPrintOutItem.wdPrintDocumentContent; 
object pageType = Word.WdPrintOutPages.wdPrintAllPages; 
object oTrue = true; 
object oFalse = false; 

this.PrintOut(
    ref oTrue, ref oFalse, ref range, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref items, ref copies, ref pages, ref pageType, ref oFalse, ref oTrue, 
    ref missing, ref oFalse, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

To specify the range, you must use the `wdPrintFromTo` or `wdPrintRangeOfPages` value with the corresponding numbers

Comment: think you,but it is not work,I know I should use wdPrintFromTo or wdPrintRangeOfPages，in fact, i only want to use wdPrintRangeOfPages, but in python. I don't know how to use the constants wdPrintRangeOfPages,

Comment: form https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdprintoutrange

Comment: i found the value of wdPrintRangeOfPages, so in my code,Range=4, as the same of Item=0 PageType=0. and these arguments(Value) work well in VBA, but not work in python.

Comment: Dc.PrintOut(Range=Word.WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintRangeOfPages, Item=Word.WdPrintOutItem.wdPrintDocumentContent,Pages="2", PageType=Word.WdPrintOutPages.wdPrintAllPages)

Comment: This code is also not work, i get  the AttributeError, is this problem about pywin32?